# If SSL certificate expired, will it get automatically deleted?

Tags: ssl

Our website is http://example.com is redirecting to https://example.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi
So maybe our SSL certificate expired? I can't see the SSL cert. in the cPanel list of SSL certificates.
My question is: Will the expired SSL be automatically deleted if it expired?

Comment: Can you specify what web server (and OS) you're using? They may behave differently.

Comment: Questions about cPanel and other management software are off-topic here.

Comment: @sebix Yep. The fact that this question cannot be tagged properly with the available tags should have been a hint.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 2):

It will not be deleted because the certificate is on your server but it will be known that it expired and browsers will react appropriately, an unsecured site.

Comment: Hi Rob thanks. Hhmm I'll try again with the .htaccess HTTPS redirect to HTTP only..

Related issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29272180/htaccess-redirect-domain-https-to-http